# Information on laravel API

Tags: laravel, api

I need clear information about laravel API.

I've been reading lots of articles about laravel API. Beside choosing between JWT and laravel-passport—which is a whole different level of confusion—I need to get basic information about laravel API to make it clearer to me what's what.

## Questions

1. Why does laravel passport need a database (what's the usage of those tables)?
2. If I change auth driver to passport in authProvider file, and not use api, would it affect my normal auth behavior?
3. If i use API (passport) do I *have to* use laravel-echo or any js library?

Comment: Laravel passport uses JWT

Comment: @pr1nc3 thwn why some people install jwt instead of passport?

Comment: You said you read a lot of articles that should be the first thing that you faced.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745884/laravel-passport-vs-jwt-vs-oauth2-vs-auth0

Comment: @pr1nc3 that's i should read on pc, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Laravel passport needs database to store tokens that are generated and  used during authorization. Also, needs to bind these tokens to a specific users.

There are actually 5 new tables that are generated from migrations when installing Laravel Passport:

https://github.com/laravel/passport/tree/7.0/database/migrations

About using Laravel Echo or any js library is optional, and Laravel Passport does not require any of these.

See the Laravel Passport composer.json on requirements and other dependencies:

https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/7.0/composer.json

Comment: And just a small add laravel JWT(Tymon) holds user data to verify and is part of the Authorization header. But the token is generated and passed as a header + has expiration time but is not stored anywhere (unless you want to but there is no reason)